# J. F. Adams Proof of Cellular Approximation Theorem

Tags: gn.general-topology, mapping-class-groups, groupoids

In Ronald Brown's discussion of the proof of The Cellular Approximation Theorem in *Topology and Groupoids* Sec. 7.6 he writes that, "the elegant formulation of the proof is due to J. F. Adams." Does anyone know if Adams' version of the proof is contained in the literature? I could find no mention of such a proof in Adams' Student Guide to Topology or in a general search.

Comment: Given that Ronald Brown thanks Frank Adams for his comments in the preface, it might well be that the "elegant formulation" was provided to him in person, rather than through a publication.

Comment: Very possibly. There are a number of similarities between Brown's exposition and pg. 40-41 of JHC Whitehead's Combinatorial Homotopy paper. In Student's Guide Adams highlights this aspect of Whitehead's paper explicitly as well as the introduction of the term cellular map and cellular homotopy. I would be very interested in any direct reference to cellular maps in some of Adams' other work.